# Add a predefined message to a Facebook "Post to Your Wall" dialog using FB.ui

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm using `FB.ui` (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.ui/) to create the "Post to Your Wall" feature on my website:

```
var new_post = {
    method: 'feed',
    link: '/path/to/my/site',
    picture: '/path/to/image.jpg',
    name: 'My Site',
    caption: 'Lorem',
    description: 'Ipsum',
    message: 'Check out this link, guys!' //this does not work
};
FB.ui(new_post, callback_defined_somewhere);
```

How do I add a predefined message to the post, e.g. "Check out this link, guys!"

I've tried adding the `message` parameter to the `new_post` object, but that doesn't seem to work.

When the dialog is shown, focus is on the text box, with `Say something about this...` instead of the `Check out this link, guys!` message.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It has been removed from FB API  since Jan 1st, 2012 and completely removed after July 5th, 2012. see http://developers.facebook.com/docs/fbjs/

So nowadays you cannot specify the text of the message in any way.

Comment: @Aayush Khandelwal: if you refute my answer with any working example - it would be great :-)

Comment: na actually i am searching for this thing for quite a long period . so if you are sure then i should stop searching it

Comment: @Aayush Khandelwal: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/ --- you can see that there is no any parameter to specify the text. So, no property -> no ability

Comment: the answer is correct, this has been removed. the message field should only be user generated anyway, that´s why it is forbidden to use automatic text with the php sdk (where the message parameter still works).

Comment: @luschn:So i cant have the user see the prompt box with some predefined text in the textbox.Would php-sdk work in this case?I have been after this for a long time now..this is what i have done..i dont find any good solution for it..this is what i have done

http://www.arrowlife.com/stitchless_campaign/opa/fbshare.php

please help me solve this problem...by commenting or replying in the chat

http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37811/facebook-auto-sharingsome-api

Comment: @zerkms:please see the above comment

Comment: @OPUS: You cannot specify it using facebook API. That's it. And it doesn't matter what SDK you're using.

Comment: well, you can define the message with the php sdk, but it is not allowed to use your own content. any message or caption ALWAYS has to be 100% user generated. you are also not allowed to prefill a text field before the user sends something with the php sdk. is has to be emtpy. again, 100% user generated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Open Graph Protocol.

Add this to your html tag: `<html xmlns:og="http://opengraphprotocol.org/schema/">`

And include this in your `<head>` tag.

```
<meta property="og:title" content="Link title text!"/>
<meta property="og:type" content="website"/>
<meta property="og:url" content="http://example.com/"/>
<meta property="og:site_name" content="Link title text!"/>
<meta property="og:description" content="Link description text!"/>
<meta property="og:image" content="http://example.com/fbshare.png"/>
```

If you want multiple messages for the same url you can use `?something` and if `isset($_GET['something'])` then change the og tags as you wish.

Comment: This cool, but you need to upload the picture to a server first.